# Break Links PowerPoint 2010

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have been struggling with C# and PowerPoint, I posted earlier about how to update Links in ppt using C# if the links were set to manual, I didn't get any responses so I figured I would try to circumvent the issue by setting the links to automatic in the file, then when C# opens it it updates them, saves the file, and then breaks them and saves it as another file name, but that hasn't proven any easier.

All I need to know is how to break the links. I know some VBA and wrote a code to break them, but when I call a macro in C# with a RunMacro method it doesn't seem to be working with the method I am using (? - I'm new to C# so I don't fully understand why this is, but if you Google "run macro PowerPoint C#" you will find the way I am sure I tried to go about it.) Please help, I am at a complete loss.

My script looks something like this

```
Using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

public void Main()
    {

        PowerPoint.Application ppt = new PowerPoint.Application();
        PowerPoint.Presentation PRS = ppt.Presentations.Open(@"Filename.pptm",
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);


        PRS.UpdateLinks();
        PRS.Save
        //here is where I need to break the links
        PRS.SaveAs(@"filename with links broken.pptm", 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentationMacroEnabled, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        PRS.Close(); 
       ppt.Quit();
}
```

I tried setting the linkformat to manual before opening the file, but that doesn't affect any shapes that are already created, only new ones created within the program afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a similar project in Powerpoint which also involves breaking links.  In my program I am reading from an Excel file and take this data and put it into a Powerpoint presentation.  In my Powerpoint template file I have all of my links to my Excel file laid out and formatted the way that I want it to look.  The program begins to run and this fills the Excel file.  After the writing to Excel is finished, I open up Powerpoint and UpdateLinks() to my presentation.  Once the links are updated I break the links using a for loop on the Shapes in the Powerpoint.  After, I save and close the document.  Below is my function that I use to create my Powerpoint file based off of each of my ppt file templates (for my example I iterate through multiple ppt files because each ppt file contains only one slide.  They are all combined into one slideshow later in the process).

```
public void CreatePowerpoint()
    {
        string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string file = fileArray[i];

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation powerpoint = pptApp.Presentations.Open(file);
            powerpoint.UpdateLinks();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides slides = powerpoint.Slides;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide slide = slides[1];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes pptShapes = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes)slide.Shapes;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape y in pptShapes)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape j = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)y;
                try
                {
                    //If auto link update is disabled for links
                    //j.LinkFormat.j.Update();
                    if (j.LinkFormat != null)
                    {
                        j.LinkFormat.BreakLink();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }

            powerpoint.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test" + i + ".pptx");
            powerpoint.Close();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
        pptApp.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing things before opening a file will have no effect on files that aren't open, of course.  Iterate through the shapes collection on each slide and for each shape:

```
If .Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
    .LinkFormat.BreakLink
End If
```

msoLinkedOLEObject = 10